# Import VB.NET DLL into C#.Net Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, dll

I am trying to get a VB.NET DLL used as a reference on a aspx.cs page.

I have added the compiled DLL and it's resources to a bin folder, and I have added the reference and added

```
using my_DLL;
```

Then I go to call a function like this....

```
public string foobar = concat_function_DLL("foo" , "bar");
```

but, I get the red sqwiggles under concat_function_DLL (my DLL function) and this message :

```
"The name 'concat_function_DLL' does not exist in the current context
```

---

I have tried removing the bin folder, removing the reference, re-creating the bin folder and then re-adding the reference, but it still doesn't want to recognize anything from my DLL.

The DLL will work completely fine from my VB.Net webpage so I know it cannot be a problem with the DLL. Maybe there is some step I am missing? I thought I read that .NET DLLs are interchangeable between both vb.net and c#.net.

Thank you!

Comment: I should add that I can open my_DLL.xml and read it perfectly fine from the bin folder, so the DLL *is* there.... but if I click on my_DLL and try to 'peak deffinition' it says "Cannot navigate to definition"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> public string foobar = concat_function_DLL("foo" , "bar");

You are calling a method, `concat_function_DLL`, but you aren't specifying the type that declares it.

C# won't automatically put "global" methods from VB.NET modules in scope. Use this:

```
public string foobar = YourModuleName.concat_function_DLL("foo" , "bar");
```

Or, if you are using C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015), then you can use the VB.NET module and use it as you were before. Add this using statement:

```
using static my_DLL.YourModuleName;
```

Then you can just use the method as you were previously.

Comment: Great! I am only on VS2013 but your first solution did it for me! I did not know that I had to go like this MyDLL.StringTools.concat_fuction_DLL("foo", "bar"); thanks  so much!